# Extracting Count of Distinct Values from one column based on filter from another column

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have multiple excel sheets where I need to extract the count of distinct values from column A associated with different comments(Column Q), logins(Column J) and brand name(Column S). I have a faulty macro which creates a pivot table to display the counts from column A on the basis of the other parameters, the issue with it is the macro always crashes the first time I run it and I have to manually select and deselect at least one parameter from the pivot value fields for it to run. Is there a simpler way to do this?
Code:-

```
Sub GeneratePivot()
Dim objSheetWithData As Worksheet
Dim objSheetWithPivot As Worksheet
Dim objListObjectWithData As ListObject
Dim objConnection As WorkbookConnection
Dim objPivotCache As PivotCache
Dim objPivotTable As PivotTable
Dim objCubeField As CubeField
Dim objPivotField As PivotField
    
Set objSheetWithData = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set objSheetWithPivot = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)

If objSheetWithData.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
    Set objListObjectWithData = objSheetWithData.ListObjects(1)
Else
    Set objListObjectWithData = objSheetWithData.ListObjects.Add( _
        SourceType:=xlSrcRange, _
        Source:=objSheetWithData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, _
        XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes)
End If

For Each objConnection In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
    If objConnection.Type = xlConnectionTypeWORKSHEET Then objConnection.Delete
Next objConnection

Set objConnection = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Add2( _
    Name:="My Connection", _
    Description:="My Connection Description", _
    ConnectionString:="WORKSHEET;" & ActiveWorkbook.Name, _
    CommandText:=objListObjectWithData.Parent.Name & "!" & objListObjectWithData.Name, _
    lCmdtype:=XlCmdType.xlCmdExcel, _
    CreateModelConnection:=True, _
    ImportRelationships:=False)

Set objPivotCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlExternal, _
    SourceData:=objConnection)
With objPivotCache
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
End With

For Each objPivotTable In objSheetWithPivot.PivotTables
    objPivotTable.TableRange2.Clear
Next objPivotTable

Set objPivotTable = objPivotCache.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=objSheetWithPivot.Range("A1"))
With objPivotTable
    .Name = "Comments"
    .ColumnGrand = True
    .HasAutoFormat = True
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Comments").CubeFields("[Table1].[Login]")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Comments").CubeFields( _
    "[Table1].[Protected Brand]")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Comments").CubeFields("[Table1].[QA Comments]")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 3
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Comments").CubeFields.GetMeasure "[Table1].[SKU]", _
    xlCount, "Count of ASIN"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Comments").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "Comments").CubeFields("[Measures].[Count of ASIN]"), "Count of SKU"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Comments").PivotFields( _
    "[Measures].[Count of SKU]")
    .Caption = "Distinct Count of SKU"
    .Function = xlDistinctCount
End With
End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you share some images, one with the desired result?